# What innerHTML internally does to the DOM?

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

Consider the snippet-

```
<html >
    <script>    
        function  test(){

            function getPosition(parent, descendant) {
                return parent.compareDocumentPosition(descendant);
            }
            var p = document.getElementById("myPara");
            console.log(getPosition(document, p));          // 20


            console.log(document.body.innerHTML);           

            document.body.innerHTML += "<p>It's clobberin' time!</p>";
            console.log(getPosition(document, p));          // 37 WHY?


            console.log(document.getElementById("myPara") === p); // false WHY?
        }

    </script>
    <body>
        <p id="myPara">Its a paragraph</p>
        <button onclick="test()">Press Me!</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

The `document.body.innerHTML`before the assignation prints

```
"
        <p id="myPara">Its a paragraph</p>
        <button onclick="test()">Press Me!</button>

"
```

on the console.

2 questions here-

1. Why is `console.log(getPosition(document, p));          // 37 WHY?`
   The element `<p>It's clobberin' time!</p>` was appended to the
   innerHTML but why did it messed the position of the element
   identified by `myPara`.
2. Secondly, `console.log(document.getElementById("myPara") === p); //    false`, WHY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because every time you set `innerHTML`, the HTML document is re-parsed, a DOM is constructed and added to your document. This also invalidates all your existing refferences to your DOM elements.

The right approach is to create a new element and append it to the document body. This way you avoid the whole mess presented above, at least for the browsers that don't do any optimizations for this kind of usage (not sure if any do?)

Replace your append line:

```
       document.body.innerHTML += "<p>It's clobberin' time!</p>";
```

with this:

```
        var myElement = document.createElement('p');
        myElement.innerHTML = '<p>Its clobbering time</p>';
        document.body.appendChild(myElement);
```

Now you will see that:

```
        console.log(getPosition(document, p)); // is still 20
        console.log(document.getElementById("myPara") === p); // is now TRUE
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't usually see .innerHTML += often. I suppose that can add on to whatever is already in the element... The .innerHTML is meant to change the contents of whatever object/element it is fed to in the DOM if it is set as an rvalue '='.

2. Its false because it's more than just an empty element and you're using === which means type and value.